# multiple controllers vs single controller

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, frameworks

I have 5 different modules each of which is a separate sub-system with a controller independent of others. Now I want to build a single system comprises of these 5 modules (no need to change modules).

I am a little bit confused, as to which approach is best to use for this kind of system.

1. Should I develop a single controller to co-ordinate with all five module controllers (means a controller for co-ordination of other controllers) to make use of modules.
2. Should I combine the functionality of all five controllers and put them in a single controller (means only single controller for the system).

Its my academic task. Please explain the best approach to choose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just make the controllers pass each other information? I would advise against combining all functionality into one controller.

Comment: What the terms "sub-system", "system" and "module" mean in your interpretation? And what are the goals of this change, that you described?

Comment: creating single vs multiple controller is a debatable question, the best practice is to have a separate controller for a different module, it will make your controller specific to module. easy main-table and following best practices for coding.

Comment: generally we creates areas if the modules itself is very complex and can be considered as sub poject, or you also have have modules workging as a independant plugable area just like MVVM (see link below). <br/> http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.in/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html

Comment: Thanks to all. Actually sub-systems are already existing working independent systems and now to make a large system I am combining theses sub-systems into a single one. these all sub-systems are working as independent of each other. One thing I would like to ask here is this a good idea to control several controllers through a single controller in a single system. Thanks again for clarifications..

Comment: Try to think of it in term of domains. Separate all of your functional concerns into logical areas with clearly defined borders, then the name of that area becomes the name of your controller. The default MVC3 app does this with the Account controller.

Answer (score 0):

Good approach is that you should create separate control for each module.
By this approach you can maintain logic of each module in easily

You can also look at the following link :

[What is the advantage of using multiple Controller classes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027115/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-multiple-controller-classes-in-asp-net-mvc)